# Regex in R - omit group

Tags: r, regex

I'm starting to work with regex in R and need some help. 
I would like to match a string but without some specific group in the middle of it.Example:

```
string <- "ABCDEFG"
```

I want to capture:

```
"ABFG"
```

I have tried:

```
stringi::stri_extract_first(str = string, regex = "AB(?!CDE)FG")
```

but I get:

```
  [NA]
```

Can anyone help me?

Edit:

I'll try to be more specific. I have some positions each in one line that are separated with page numers and footers. Something like:

```
8151A0 ZAX
8131A9)
7421A7
8481A1

FOOTER
PAGE1

BRAK NR
1211Q2
865100)
BN

FOOTER
PAGE2

616100)
BRAK NR
```

I would like to extract all positions without footers and pages so my expected output is:

```
8151A0 ZAX
8131A9)
7421A7
8481A1
BRAK NR
1211Q2
865100)
BN
616100)
BRAK NR
```

Comment: Here is one option using backreferencing to extract everything around your unwanted sequence `gsub("(.*)(?:CDE)(.*)", "\\1\\2", "ABCDEFG",  perl = T )`.

Comment: You have multiple options... `^(AB).*(FG)$` with what you want in the first and second groups. `^(AB).*\KFG$` with what you want in the first and zeroth groups. `^AB|FG$`, which doesn't use groups, but does exactly what you're looking for (everything in zeroth group).

Comment: Honestly, now that I've read your question over multiple times, I'm not sure what you're asking... Could you clarify your question? Give us sample inputs and expected outputs based on those inputs.

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels - I've updated my question - is it clear for you now?

Comment: @PawełTalarek that's actually much better. Are footer and page# always the same and in those formats? (So `FOOTER` is always the text and `PAGE#` where `#` represents any number is also consistent). Based on that input (and assuming it's consistent), the easiest regex would be `[\r\n]\s*[\r\n]^FOOTER$[\r\n]^PAGE\d+[\r\n]\s*[\r\n]`.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work, it will capture 2 groups if `CDE` is in the middle, `$1` and `$2`, and will capture a single one if it is not.

```
^((?:(?!CDE).)*)(?:CDE)?(.*)$
```

Substitute with `$1$2` to extract the `CDE`

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/T2BIrE/2)

Comment: @Paweł Talarek, here you can see, that it depends on what you want to focus on, the sequence you do not want or the sequence you want. Compare to above comment.